# Can you use a MongoDB document ID as a key in another document?

Tags: database, mongodb, database-design, web-applications, nosql

I'm trying to implement a cart collection for an e-commerce app in MongoDB Atlas and am unsure of the correct way to reference the products in a user's cart which are in a separate collection.

Can I use a product's document id as a key in the cart document? I.e.

```
cart = {
   productID1: productQty1,
   productID2: productQty2,
   ...
}
```

Or do I need to do something like this:

```
cart = [
   {
    productID: productID1,
    qty: productQty1,
   },
   {
    productID: productID2,
    qty pro
   },
   ...
]
```

where productID1 is the _id of the corresponding product document in the product collection?

Since _id is of type ObjectID, I'm unsure of whether I can/should use it as a key which is of type string, or whether there are potential problems with using docIDs as keys rather than values.

Answer (score 0):

If doing this yourself (i.e without an object modelling library such as Mongoose), your second option is the most favourable design. As per the [docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/database-references/#manual-references) for Manual References:

> A manual reference is the practice of including one document's _id field in another document. The application can then issue a second query to resolve the referenced fields as needed.

For example:

```
db.products.findOne(); // Find first item in products collection
// Returns
{
   _id: ObjectId("64f8cd127f6c107e984014fc"),
   name: 'Hat',
}

db.users.findOne({ _id : ObjectId("64f8cbb87f6c107e984014f5")}); // Find a user by their _id
// Returns
{
   _id: ObjectId("64f8cbb87f6c107e984014f5"),
   first_name: 'Bob',
   last_name: 'Smith',
   address: '123 Tree Lane'
}

db.carts.findOne({ user_id : ObjectId("64f8cbb87f6c107e984014f5") }); // Find a cart by user_id
// Returns
{
   _id: ObjectId("64f8cd507f6c107e984014ff"),
   product_id: ObjectId("64f8cd127f6c107e984014fc"), // Hat
   user_id: ObjectId("64f8cbb87f6c107e984014f5") // Bob
}
```

You can then perform a [$lookup](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#-lookup--aggregation-) to join the documents similar to a left join in SQL.

```
db.carts.aggregate([
  { $match: { user_id: ObjectId("64f8cbb87f6c107e984014f5") } }, // Find Bob's cart
  {
    $lookup: // Now lookup Bob's details and add them as "user_details"
      {
        from: "users",
        localField: "user_id",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "user_details"
      }
   }
])
// Returns
[
   {
      _id: ObjectId("64f8cd507f6c107e984014ff"),
      product_id: ObjectId("64f8cd127f6c107e984014fc"),
      user_id: ObjectId("64f8cbb87f6c107e984014f5"),
      user_details: [
         {
            _id: ObjectId("64f8cbb87f6c107e984014f5"),
            first_name: 'Bob',
            last_name: 'Smith',
            address: '123 Tree Lane'
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

This makes managing the data based on `_id` simple to manage.

However, this is very much like a relational databse design, and MongoDB is NoSQL so is tailored to leverage storing documents in one another. I would suggest you read about [embedded documents](https://www.mongodb.com/basics/embedded-mongodb) and use them where you can.

Your `cart` could store an array of `product_id` like so:

```
db.carts.findOne({ user_id : ObjectId("64f8cbb87f6c107e984014f5") }); // Find a cart by user_id
// Returns
{
  _id: ObjectId("64f8cd507f6c107e984014ff"),
  products:[
     { product_id: ObjectId("64f8cd127f6c107e984014fc") }, // Hat,
     { product_id: ObjectId("64f8d35c7f6c107e98401512") } // Something else
  ],
  user_id: ObjectId("64f8cbb87f6c107e984014f5") // Bob
}
```

Then if you wanted to join the product details in you could like so:

```
db.carts.aggregate([
  { $match: { user_id: ObjectId("64f8cbb87f6c107e984014f5") } }, // Find Bob's cart
  {
    $lookup: // Now lookup the product details add them as "product_details"
      {
        from: "products",
        localField: "products.product_id",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "product_details"
      }
   }
])
// Returns
[
   {
      _id: ObjectId("64f8cd507f6c107e984014ff"),
      user_id: ObjectId("64f8cbb87f6c107e984014f5"),
      products: [
         { product_id: ObjectId("64f8cd127f6c107e984014fc") },
         { product_id: ObjectId("64f8d35c7f6c107e98401512") }
      ],
      product_details: [
         { _id: ObjectId("64f8cd127f6c107e984014fc"), name: 'Hat' },
         { _id: ObjectId("64f8d35c7f6c107e98401512"), name: 'Shoe' }
      ]
   }
]
```